# Best way to utilize rails activerecord abstractions for this query?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So, I have the following sql query that I'm using to pull some relevant information from a database. I want to utilize activerecord abstractions to optimize this query for a rails app. What is the best way to do this?

```
select count(s.app_id) counters , app.name, app.app_id from subscriptions s, apps app where s.app_id = app.id group by s.app_id order by counters;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guss you models like this

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :app
end

class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
end
```

you can alter apps add a column named subscriptions_count to use acitverecord's  counter_cache feature,then modify your model like this:

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions,:counter_cache => subscriptions_count
end
```

and you can query apps:

```
App.find(:all, :order => "subscriptions_count DESC")
```